# Scala skip when key not found in map

Tags: scala

I am trying to do the following for the case when I do not find the key in a `Map`

```
val states = Seq(Ca, Wa, Ny)
val tuples: Seq[Any] = for(state <- states) yield {
  val mapValue: Option[CustomCaseClass] = someMap.get(key)
  mapValue match {
    case Some(value) => {
      //do some operations and return a tuple (String, String)
    }
    case _ => //do nothing, just continue the for loop
  }
}
```

For the `case _` I want to do nothing and simple continue the loop. But with the above code, I am not able to do a `toMap` on `tuples` and I get the following error -

`Cannot prove that Any <:< (String, String)`

This is due to the fact that it may not always return Seq[(String,String)]. I want to be able to do operations on `tuples` and I simple want to skip the case when its not found. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following setup:

```
sealed trait State
case object Ca extends State
case object Wa extends State
case object Ny extends State

val someMap = Map(Ca -> 1, Wa -> 2)
val states = Seq(Ca, Wa, Ny)
```

We can use `Option` as another generator in the same `for` comprehension:

```
val tuples: Seq[(String, String)] = for {
    state <- states
    value <- someMap.get(state)
} yield (state.toString, value.toString + "x")
```

`Option` will be implicitly converted to a collection of 0 to 1 elements, so for `None` all the following code will be skipped and we will get this:

```
assert(tuples.toMap == Map("Ca" -> "1x", "Wa" -> "2x"))
```

You can also insert an arbitrary check inside `for`, so you can check for key presense and use `someMap(key)`, not `someMap.get(key)`:

```
val tuples2: Seq[(String, String)] = for {
    state <- states
    if someMap.contains(state)
} yield (state.toString, someMap(state).toString + "x")

assert(tuples2.toMap == Map("Ca" -> "1x", "Wa" -> "2x"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `case _` it's returning `nothing` so the `result` type is `Seq[Any]`, you can filter the **not found** element and do the `map`:

```
val tuples: Seq[(String, String)] = 
    states.filter(i => someMap.get(i).nonEmpty).map(value => (myString, myString))
```

Comment: Empty case returns `Unit`, not `nothing`. Besides, you don't need to `map.get(i).nonEmpty`, you can simply use `map.contains(i)`